# SEO impact using hash urls?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, seo

I want to use some back button support like some listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin). Since the page is usually loaded by javascript looking at the hash tags. Will it create a problem for search indexing ? Do Yahoo/Google/Bing execute the javascript to get the content ? I am also thinking of using the HTML5 state push for urls instead of hashtags wherever applicable.

Example :- If i have a site www.a.com and clicking on a link it becomes www.a.com/#!/about . When there is a seperate request for www.a.com/#!/about the javascript will take care of loading the content. But how will search engine take care of this. What would I have to do to make this work.

Since I am starting out now, and want to create a complete ajax site with PHP at backend and Javascript using Jquery in the frontend. Any helpful resources I can look at ?

Comment: If you build your site to be powered by JavaScript you'll be alienating a lot of users and every search engine but Google. And even then, crawling ajax content is new and probably not advisable to do.

Comment: @john-conde Alienating users ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: JavaScript is not accessible. So if a user has JavaScript disabled they can't get to your content. Search engines generally do not process JavaScript especially Ajax. So this means anyone with JavaScript disabled, including every other search engine except Google, will not be able to view your content. That's a very bad thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [here](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-to-allow-google-to-crawl-ajax-content) how to use hashbangs for SEO friendly AJAX-Links.

[Official Google help page](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/web/ajaxcrawling/index.html) about AJAX and crawlability.

Basically you serve a HTML fragment equivalent to the loaded content through a special query for each page.

Take a look at the [HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

Comment: Any Jquery plugin you know of which uses HTML5 history API for HTML5 supported browsers and use hashbang style for older browsers ?

Comment: It's not that easy. For the hashbang URLs you need a backend. For the history API not necessarily. Maybe there is though, but I haven't heard of any.

Comment: Agreed. But the backend for both may be nearly same if I write an apache handler to handle all the requests.